# some questions about Aggregate running mechanism

Tags: mongodb

Aggregate1:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      ...
    }
  },
  {
    $limit: 1
  }
])
```

Aggregate2:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $limit: 1
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      ...
    }
  }
])
```

Aggregate1 and Aggregate2 are different?

In Aggregate1,is the whole collection scanned firstly, then do $lookup?

If it is different,how to lookup with some query?just like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'collection2',
      localField: 'field',
      foreignField: 'field',
      as: 'newField',
      // do some query when lookup
      query: {'newField.xxx': 1}
    }
  }
])
```

I know, i can do this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'collection2',
      localField: 'field',
      foreignField: 'field',
      as: 'newField'
    }
  },
  {$unwind: '$newField'},
  {$match: {'newField.xxx': 1}}
])
```

But I'm afraid that, like the example above, the entire collection will be scanned。

Look forward to your reply!

Now,i find this api:[$graphLookup.restrictSearchWithMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/#with-a-query-filter),but:

> NOTE
>
> You cannot use any aggregation expression in this filter.
>
> For example, a query document such as
>
> ```
> { lastName: { $ne: "$lastName" } }
> ```
>
> will not work in this context to find documents in which the lastName
>   value is different from the lastName value of the input document,
>   because "$lastName" will act as a string literal, not a field path.

Comment: You can't contain the document in the lookup stage. Look up does a left join, so the option you have is to limit what is going into the look up stage. just the way you would filter docs in aggregation. The graph lookup does a recursive look up so is the reason for that option.

Comment: The last example that you put in which includes unwind and match is optimized to work with lookup. So it may not be that bad. Take a look at this https://jira.mongodb.org/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/SERVER-21612

Comment: @SagarReddy I'm still not sure if it will be combined.

Comment: I hope this will confirm. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/

Comment: @SagarReddy OK,thanks a lot!I will make a try by using Aggregate explain and tell you the result

Comment: @SagarReddy yes!you are right!mongo auto do many optimization!Thanks again!

Comment: I find that when unwind sets preserveNullAndEmptyArrays true,it will not use the optimization.And when using $redact or Array $filter,the optimization also doesn't work.It just supports $match and the query must contain only fields from $lookup.